# Powerpoint Code to Retain Linked Images When Sharing File

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In my Powerpoint have images that are linked to a folder. I need to send this to a user that does not have access to the folder. I need the images to retain the current content.

I have tried to manually copy and re-paste as image AS PICTURE then send the PowerPoint, this works and this retains the content and date setting in the images.

How could I programatically do this as I have 32 PowerPoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For distributing a presentation, I think you probably have the best solution already, but here's another that'd be useful in some circumstances.

PowerPoint will nearly always create fully pathed links, but if then link is to just the filename, no path, it'll (generally) look in the same folder for the image as the PPT/PPTX itself.

So if you're willing to distribute the linked images as well as the PowerPoint file and can get the recipient to put them all together in one folder, all you need to do is set the linked picture's .LinkFormat.SourceFullName to just the original image file name, sans path.

Obviously, this won't be as simple to distribute, but since it changes nothing about the picture but the link path, it retains any animations, alt text, tags or other unusual formatting settings you might have applied to the image.

The other, perhaps simplest, trick is to choose Link & Embed rather than just Link when inserting the image. PPT will then update the image in the presentation when the original image on disk changes, but uses the embedded copy if the link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

This one was a fun challenge!

The `CopyPictures` macro is really the only macro that you need, but I'm including the other two that I used to set up and debug the whole situation.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPictures()

    Dim currentSlide As Slide
    For Each currentSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides

        Dim currentShape As Shape
        For Each currentShape In currentSlide.Shapes

            If currentShape.Type = msoLinkedPicture Then

                'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.addpicture
                currentSlide.Shapes.AddPicture _
                    currentShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, _
                    msoFalse, msoTrue, _
                    currentShape.Left, currentShape.Top, _
                    currentShape.Width, currentShape.Height

                currentShape.Delete

            End If

        Next currentShape

    Next currentSlide

End Sub
```

The `CopyPictures` macro loops through every shape in every slide of the powerpoint and says that if the current shape it's inspecting has type `msoLinkedPicture`, it will simply re-add that picture to the powerpoint using the link it's based on but instead choose for the picture to be saved *with* the document as an `msoPicture`! The new picture is placed at the same location and is scaled to match the current picture. Finally, it deletes the 'old' linked version of the picture since it has already been replaced.

---

The `AddLinkedPicture` macro was used to add a linked picture to my active slide and then I used the second macro, `ShapeTypeDebug`, to make sure that the picture I added had the proper type, `msoLinkedPicture`.

You can use the `ShapeTypeDebug` macro to check whether any of the shapes on the current slide are a picture. I used this before and after running the `CopyPictures` macro to make sure that the pictures were properly 'converted'.

```
Sub AddLinkedPicture()

    'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.addpicture
    ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes.AddPicture "C:\Users\Public\Downloads\Untitled.png", msoTrue, msoFalse, 100, 100

End Sub

Sub ShapeTypeDebug()

    Dim currentShape As Shape
    For Each currentShape In ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes

        'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.msoshapetype?view=office-pia
        Select Case currentShape.Type
            Case 11
                MsgBox Chr(34) & currentShape.Name & Chr(34) & " is a msoLinkedPicture"
            Case 13
                MsgBox Chr(34) & currentShape.Name & Chr(34) & " is a msoPicture "
        End Select

    Next currentShape

End Sub
```

Note that the method I'm using doesn't make a copy of the **current** picture, so if you've done some other editing to it within powerpoint, my method will lose that editing.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's nearly there! The only thing that didn't quite work was >> The new picture is placed at the same location and is scaled to match the current picture. >> The positioning of the pictures moved and I had to scale manually. Any ideas?

Comment: @Camille how long ago did you grab the code? I made a little update to it about 30 minutes ago because I had done one part of it backwards :|

Comment: Excellent @ Marcucciboy2 I have been thinking about something like this ‘Shape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName’ to search for different linked ole object scattered across the directories to save them in single consolidated directory.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution of @Marcucciboy2 is a good approach but does not cover pictures within shape groups. Furthermore, it seems to have problems adding linked pictures with a source like *cid:image001.jpg@01D5DDD1.4B33D890*.

Therefore, I have enhanced the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPictures()

    Dim currentSlide As Slide
    For Each currentSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides

        Dim currentShape As Shape
        For Each currentShape In currentSlide.Shapes

            HandleShape currentSlide:=currentSlide, currentShape:=currentShape 

        Next currentShape

    Next currentSlide

End Sub

Private Sub HandleShape(currentSlide As Slide, currentShape As Shape)

    If currentShape.Type = msoGroup Then

        Dim groupNames() As String
        ReDim Preserve groupNames(1 To currentShape.GroupItems.Count + 1)

        Dim groupIndex As Integer
        groupIndex = 0

        Dim shapeWasCopied As Boolean
        shapeWasCopied = False

        Dim groupShape As Shape
        For Each groupShape In currentShape.GroupItems

            groupIndex = groupIndex + 1
            groupNames(groupIndex) = groupShape.Name

            If groupShape.Type = msoLinkedPicture Then

                HandleShape currentSlide:=currentSlide, currentShape:=groupShape

                shapeWasCopied = True

            End If

        Next groupShape

        If (shapeWasCopied) Then

            currentSlide.Shapes.Range(groupNames).Group

        End If

    ElseIf currentShape.Type = msoLinkedPicture Then

        Dim newShape As Object
        Dim newName As String

        newName = currentShape.Name

        currentShape.Copy
        Set newShape = currentSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture, DisplayAsIcon:=msoFalse, Link:=msoFalse)

        With newShape
            .Width = currentShape.Width
            .Height = currentShape.Height
            .Left = currentShape.Left
            .Top = currentShape.Top
        End With

        currentShape.Delete

        newShape.Name = newName

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End If

End Sub
```